# How to extract date information from the text data?

Tags: python, string, extract

Here is the text data:
text = 'PRINT EDITIONNew Survey Suggests An Alarming Increase  In Physician Burnout|September 30, 2022, Page A25'
I want the the only information "September 30, 2022".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may do a regex find all on the pattern:

```
\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4}
```

Sample script:

```py
text = 'PRINT EDITIONNew Survey Suggests An Alarming Increase In Physician Burnout|September 30, 2022, Page A25'
dates = re.findall(r'\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4}', text)
print(dates)  # ['September 30, 2022']
```